# Android reload swap cursorAdapter to do a listView refresh

Tags: android, listview, refresh, reload, android-cursoradapter

Hello I am a beginner in Android programming and I have a problem with refreshing listView.

I am using `CURSORADAPTER` to show data in the `listView`, and my problem is about refreshing  the cursor to show newly inserted data!!!

I read a lot of similar problems here on StackOverflow, and I see that others talk about `swapCursor()` or `changeCursor()`, or `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` or `requery()`-DEPRECATED, but I really don't know how to do that.

I am struggling with this problem for five days now, and I really try to find some example on the web but I haven't found anything that I understand for now.

Then I made other simple app which use only two fragments, db and a `listView`.
On the first fragment `(FragmentA)` the only thing I do is insert some data in my db, on second fragment ``(FragmentB)` I have a listView that shows data from my db.

When I insert data in db on my `FragmentA`, and then go to second fragment `FragmentB` I do not get newly inserted item from db in my `listView`, and I do understand why, because of the android lifecycle `onCreateView` method from `fragmentB` was already called once when I started application, and cursor was loaded with data from db, and when I close and restart application then I get new data from db because cursor was "reloaded" when `onCreateView` was called again. I have all of this Override methods: `onCreateView`, `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onActivityCreated`, `onStart`, `onResume`, `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroyView`, `onDestroy`, `onDetach` but none of these methods were called again when I use only 2 fragments and this is also what I understand why is happening, so I used `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` method to try to refresh cursor when `FragmentB` was loaded.

I also found some unanswered questions on this topic, so I think, maybe that the answer to my question can contribute to others on the StackOverflow community in the future.

THANK YOU ALL VERY MUCH!!!

This is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final MyFragmentAdapter myFragmentAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(fragmentManager); 
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentAdapter(fragmentManager));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPageScrolled position " + position);   ////THIS IS WHERE I THINK CURSOR SHOULD BE REFRESHED SOMEHOW
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

FragmentA :

public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

```
EditText editText;
Button button;
DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;
private static final String TAG = FragmentA.class.getSimpleName();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView 1");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_insert);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_insert);
    databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getContext());

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tableName = "profit";
            double price = 2;
            String insTxt = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
            Log.d(TAG, "button click = " + insTxt);
            add(tableName);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
//for insert into db
public void add(String tableName){
    long id = databaseAdapter.insertData(tableName);
    if (id < 0){
        Log.d(TAG, "BAD INSERT");
    }else {
        Log.d(TAG, "INSERT OK!!!!");
    }
}
}
```

FragmentB

public class FragmentB extends Fragment{

```
private static final String TAG = FragmentB.class.getSimpleName();
ListView listView;
EditText editText;
Button button;
//list view PART
MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    Log.d(TAG, " FragmentB onCreateView 1");
    databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getContext());
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Cursor cursor = databaseAdapter.cursorLoadingData(); // populate cursor
    myCustomAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getContext(), cursor);
    listView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
    return view;
} 
}
```

DatabaseAdapter :

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {
.....
//part for taking all data from db...
public Cursor cursorLoadingData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String myQuery = " select * from profit order by _id desc";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(myQuery, null);
    return cursor;
}
.....
}
```

MyCustomAdapter - CursorAdapter class:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String TAG = MyCustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_id);
    long ExtractedId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
    textViewId.setText(String.valueOf(ExtractedId));
}
```

}